# Detecting hitting Enter within text input

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keydown, keyup

I am trying to detect when a user hits `Enter` while still typing in a text input. The event should fire only when the 'down'ing of the key and release of the key both happen within the text input. That is, the event should not fire, if he presses `Enter` while in some other part of the body, then focuses on the input and releases it. So I tried the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("input").keyup(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13 && $(this).attr("enter") == "1") { alert("Yep!"); }
  });
$("input").keydown(function(e) {
   if (e.which == 13) { $(this).attr("enter","1"); }
});
$(document).on("keyup",function(e) { if (e.which == 13) { $("input").attr("enter","0"); } });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = 'text' enter = '0' />
</body>
</html>
```

But I am having a strange problem. When I focus out of the input and press `Enter`, the attribute `enter` of the input remains `0` as expected. But with the key still pressed, if I now focus on the input, Firebug shows the attribute becoming 1. As a result, after this if I release the key, the event is fired.

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? `keypress` doesn't work, so if you replace the entire chunk by simply

```
$("input").keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 13) { alert("Yep!"); }
  });
```

then try doing this, clicking out of the input to remove focus, then pressing `Enter` and while keeping it pressed, focus on the input. You will now see a continuous series of alerts!

Answer (score 0):

Because you have two events bind to input as below.

One inside

```
$("input").keyup(function(e){
```

and Other inside

```
$(document).on("keyup",function(e) {
```

so in first you need to use `e.stopPropagation();`